# Draw Polyline in DrawingContext using c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to draw a `Polyline` in the `Visual Layer`. Here is the code I'm using to draw a `Line`. Should I draw multiple `Lines` and add them to the `VisualCollection` or there is a better way?

```
var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
using (var dc = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
{
    var myPen = new Pen
    {
        Thickness = thickness,
        Brush = Settings.GridColor
    };
    myPen.Freeze();
    dc.DrawLine(myPen, pt1, pt2);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you missed some tags? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you would be better off using `DrawGeometry` than `DrawLine`.

Example:

```
var myPen = new Pen
{
    Thickness = thickness,
    Brush = Settings.GridColor
};
myPen.Freeze();


var geometry = new StreamGeometry();
using (StreamGeometryContext ctx = geometry.Open())
{
    ctx.BeginFigure(new Point(10, 100), true /* is filled */, true /* is closed */);
    ctx.LineTo(new Point(100, 100), true /* is stroked */, false /* is smooth join */);
    ctx.LineTo(new Point(100, 50), true /* is stroked */, false /* is smooth join */);
}
geometry.Freeze();

dc.DrawGeometry(null, myPen, geometry);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a better way, except instead of calling `myPen.Freeze()` I would just create it as a `const`. I don't know if that is really more efficient, I just think it clears the code up more in the future. I would also (personal thing) not use the `var` keyword, as it would be less ambiguous what type you create when you call `drawingVisual.RenderOpen()`.